Get stack trace from ELF and stack hex
I'm working on a core dump mechanism for STM32 mcus running FreeRTOS.
I managed to extract the stack of the running tasks, and transmit it to a server where a python script writes it into a hex file. I also have access to the ELF and source code that was used to program the STM32
My question is how can I extract useful information from this stack dump?
I'm not even looking for an automated solution, even GDB would be fine. I've read it can do that if you give it a core dump in ELF format but I dont know how to generate that
Note: The stack pointer is extracted too and I can easily add more information like additional register if that's necessary.
Thanks

It appears, that core dump facilities are not available in gdb for ARM Cortex-M targets; I am not going to dig the rabbit hole to find out the full truth.
But here may be a guide to something similar to what you want to achieve.
That guide aims higher, to reproduction of the whole state and continuation-ability. That of course requires full RAM dump, full register store/restore (which is challenging next to impossible, given peripherals and even internal registers of stack).
I tried a somewhat modified simplistic test (to achieve only backtrace) on a simplistic setup: on STM32G0, I wrote a simple program, where main() sets up timer interrupt (which toggles a pin to blink a LED, Hello World :-) ) then calls foo() which contains only an infinite loop (just to have something on stack). The timer interrupt has some dummy (but volatile) local variables and calls bar() with dummy parameters, again, just to have something interesting on stack (so, so far, we have plain function calls, interrupt handler call, local variables and parameters on the stack). I then placed a breakpoint into bar() and stored stack to stack.hex using gcc's dump command. I also wrote down content of pc, lr, sp registers.
Then I moni reset halted in gdb to stop at the reset vector, and used dump's counterpart restore to load some dummy file into RAM to thrash the stack. Confirmed that backtrace indeed sees nothing, then restored the stack, restored pc, lr, sp and the resulting backtrace was identical to the one taken at the genuine run before.
(gdb) moni reset halt
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x0800015c msp: 0x20024000
(gdb) restore n.hex
Restoring section .sec1 (0x20023fb8 to 0x20024000)
(gdb) x /8wx 0x20023fe0
0x20023fe0:     0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x20023ff0:     0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
(gdb) bt
#0  Reset_Handler () at startup_stm32g0b1xx.s:60
#1  0xffffffff in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) restore stack.hex
Restoring section .sec1 (0x20023fb8 to 0x20024000)
(gdb) set $pc=0x80000bc
(gdb) set $sp=0x20023fb8
(gdb) set $lr=0x8000159
(gdb) bt full
#0  bar (a=4294967295, b=4294967295, c=4294967295) at timer_isr.c:23
        d = 1610612736
#1  0x08000158 in TIM2_IRQHandler () at timer_isr.c:73
        a = 268751833
        b = 1915640636
        c = 3273119555
        d = 1342177280
        e = 4294967289
#2  <signal handler called>
No symbol table info available.
#3  foo () at timer_isr.c:32
No locals.
#4  0x0800010e in main () at timer_isr.c:57
No locals.
#5  0x0800018a in LoopFillZerobss () at startup_stm32g0b1xx.s:101
No locals.


That's an interesting approach.
Since I'm using FreeRTOS I have multiple SPs but I guess I can get gdb to print any stack by overwriting the MCU SP.
Do you think PC and LR are necessary for that? Mine are on the stack since I dump the task stack while it's not running. One of the main point of this whole thing is to get the LR reliably haha

I don't use preemptive multitasking a.k.a. RTOS and am not interested in investigating what automation is provided for that in the tools, sorry.

I ended up just scanning the stack hex for words that look like addresses (in the range of my flash addresses) and running them through addr2line in order.
It gives me an idea of what the stack looks like with a lot of garbage here and there since data can also look like addresses sometimes. I can also use the stack pointer to ignore what's after it, since these are just previous data that are not relevant anymore

Crude, but I see how it can be usable - the call chain at the moment of failure may be a significant source of information in itself, even without the additional context of local/auto variables on the stack.

It was done many years ago.

connect the probe
configure your favourite IDE - for example STM32CubeIDE
configure the debugging session to decode freeRTOS information.


From that moment whilst debugging you have tasks, queues, timers and semaphores information available without any special code overhead as the plunging reads the information from the chip through debug peripheral.

What you're describing is just a JTAG debugger right?
In my case I want to catch rare watchdogging events on a production line with a lot of microcontrollers, I cant just hook a JTAG connector to every one of them

You need to dump the whole SRAM memory as the call stack is far not enough

Why isn't the stack enough? What's missing? I just want a stack trace like which functions were called, it's ok if some variables are unknown
